# Users can't upload files using mobile phones

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile, file-upload

I have a form where parents can upload files (their child's completed homework) to be received by teachers. 
However, I have been getting a lot of complaints that they can't upload files when they use their mobile phones. When they click on the save button, nothing happens.

Thing is when I (superadmin) and teachers upload from our pages using either pc or mobile phones, it uploads without hitches.

Why can't parents upload files, especially with their mobile phones.

I don't know if this is a coding issue or a server issue.

For now, I use a shared cloud hosting with 4 CPU Cores, 4GB DDR4 RAM, Unlimited Bandwidth and Unlimited SSD Space.

***model***

```
  public function upload_docs($data)
    {

   $this->db->where('homework_id',$data['homework_id']);
   $this->db->where('student_id',$data['student_id']);
   $q = $this->db->get('submit_assignment');

   if ( $q->num_rows() > 0 ) 
   {
      $this->db->where('homework_id',$data['homework_id']);
       $this->db->where('student_id',$data['student_id']);
      $this->db->update('submit_assignment',$data);
   } else {

      $this->db->insert('submit_assignment',$data);
   }

    }

    // public function upload_docs($data)
    // {

    //     if (isset($data['id']) && $data['id'] != null) {

    //         $this->db->where("id", $data["id"])->update("submit_assignment", $data);
    //         return $data['id'];
    //     } else {

    //         $this->db->insert("submit_assignment", $data);
    //         return $this->db->insert_id();
    //     }
    // }
```

***controller***

```
  public function upload_docs()
    {

        $homework_id         = $_REQUEST['homework_id'];
        $student_id          =$_REQUEST['student_id'];
        $data['homework_id'] = $homework_id;
        $data['student_id']  = $student_id;
        $data['message']     = $_REQUEST['message'];
        // $data['id']=$_POST['assigment_id'];
         $is_required=$this->homework_model->check_assignment($homework_id,$student_id);
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', $this->lang->line('message'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', $this->lang->line('attach_document'), 'trim|xss_clean|callback_handle_upload['.$is_required.']');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
          $msg=array(
            'message'=>form_error('message'),
            'file'=>form_error('file'),
          );
          $array = array('status' => 'fail', 'error' => $msg, 'message' => '');

        }else{

             if (isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                $time     = md5($_FILES["file"]['name'] . microtime());
                $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $img_name = $time . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];           
            $data['docs'] =  $img_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/homework/assignment/" . $data['docs']);

            $data['file_name']=$_FILES["file"]['name'];

            $this->homework_model->upload_docs($data);
        }

         $array = array('status' => 'success', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }

    public function handle_upload($str,$is_required)
    {

        $image_validate = $this->config->item('file_validate');

        if (isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

            $file_type         = $_FILES["file"]['type'];
            $file_size         = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
            $file_name         = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $allowed_extension = $image_validate['allowed_extension'];
            $ext               = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



            $allowed_mime_type = $image_validate['allowed_mime_type'];

            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            finfo_close($finfo);

            if (!in_array($mtype, $allowed_mime_type)) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'File Type Not Allowed');
                return false;
            }

            if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_extension) || !in_array($file_type, $allowed_mime_type)) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Extension Not Allowed');
                return false;
            }

            if ($file_size > $image_validate['upload_size']) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', $this->lang->line('file_size_shoud_be_less_than') . number_format($image_validate['upload_size'] / 1048576, 2) . " MB");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
          if($is_required==0){
             $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Please choose a file to upload.');
            return false;
          }else{
             return true;
          }

        }


    }
```

***view***

```
<td class="mailbox-date pull-right">
                                                <a onclick="upload_docs('<?php echo $homework['id']; ?>', '<?php echo $upload_docsButton; ?>');" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"    data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title="<?php echo $this->lang->line('homework') . " " . $this->lang->line('assignments'); ?>">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
                                                <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="evaluation('<?php echo $homework['id']; ?>','<?php echo $hw;?>');" title="" data-target="#evaluation" data-toggle="modal"  data-original-title="Evaluation">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a>    
                                            </td>


<div class="modal fade" id="upload_docs" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="evaluation" style="padding-left: 0 !important">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-media-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-media-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="box-title"><?php echo $this->lang->line('homework'); ?> <?php echo $this->lang->line('assignments'); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <form id="upload" method="post" class="ptt10" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body pt0">
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" id="homework_id"  name="homework_id">
                                <input type="hidden" id="assigment_id" name="assigment_id">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pwd"><?php echo $this->lang->line('message'); ?></label>
                                        <textarea type="text" id="assigment_message" name="message" class="form-control "></textarea>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="pwd"><?php echo $this->lang->line('attach_document'); ?></label>
                                        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control filestyle">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p id="uploaded_docs"></p>
                            </div>

</div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <div class="" id="footer_area">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> Please wait"><?php echo $this->lang->line('save'); ?></button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hey @MamaJardel, in the code you shared, there is no save button. Are you uploading files via AJAX because there is no action in your form tag?

Comment: @sauhardnc I have modified the view file

Comment: Hey @MamaJardel, you modified the code and now the button is visible, but how do you save your form?

Comment: without action attribute, no forms should be submitted but you're saying that you(super admin) and teachers have no problem saving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is mess.
First add form action then add button form attribute like this:

```
<button type="submit" form="upload" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="submit" data-loading-text='SOME TEXT'> Please wait<?php echo $this->lang->line('save'); ?></button>


<form id="upload" role="form" method="post" class="ptt10" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_docs">
```

Comment: let me accept this. I was able to upload files when I log in as a parent. Hopefully, others will too. Thank you!